# JSON.parse returns object object

Tags: json, node.js, ajax

I am trying to get the values of item, but when I print the values in the console it displays object instead of the values. How can I access the values?

Here is my code:

```
var options2;
request.post(opts,function(error,response,body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("JSON IS =" + jsonResponse.rows);
        options2 = jsonResponse.rows.reduce((acc, obj) => acc.concat(obj['Item']), []);
    }else{
        console.log(body)
    }
});
```

What do I miss?

Comment: what type of response are you getting in body??

Comment: the actual json

Comment: @Hardik BODY IS ={
  "columns" : [ "Items" ],
  "rows" : [ {
    "Item" : "ABC"
  }, {
    "Item" : "DEF"
  } ]

Comment: response (`{ "columns" : [ "Items" ], "rows" : [ { "Item" : "ABC" }, { "Item" : "DEF" } ]`)  looks like a object you don't have to parse it again.

Answer (score 3):

Print in a new line like:

```
console.log("JSON IS =");
console.log(jsonResponse.rows);
```

Or replace '+' with a ',' like this,

```
console.log("JSON IS = ", jsonResponse.rows);
```

Comment: or you can add comma as a seperator in console.log.
**console.log("JSON IS =", jsonResponse.rows);**

Answer (score 0):

If the main idea is just to debug object data (doing console logging), you may want to use json.stringify method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify That will give you string representation of an object.

Comment: that will **not** display the actual object rather a simple string which is very difficult to read/debug.

Comment: he's using **+** with string and object that is the problem. he needs two `console.log` statements or separate current one with `,` instead of `+`

Answer (score 0):

```
var options2;
request.post(opts,function(error,response,body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
        // **wrap rows in JSON.stringify()**
        console.log("JSON IS =" + JSON.stringify(jsonResponse.rows));
        options2 = jsonResponse.rows.reduce((acc, obj) => acc.concat(obj['Item']), []);
    }else{
        console.log(body)
    }
});
```